# How to retrieve maximum or highest value from table by separate string using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to retrive highest value from one column of  table  suppose the highest value is 1002 so query will be like this.

```
1000
1001
1002

            SELECT max(column1 ) as max_page FROM abc; 

    output will be 1002 as highest value but if column data contain string with this valuefor example 

    XYZ1000
    XYZ1001
    XYZ1002


    in this case it is not working of max(column) way so  how to separate string and get maximum value .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with your problem is to define a column function that returns only the numeric part of the column1.

*If all your column1 start with XYZ*

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(column1, 4, length(column1)-3) AS UNSIGNED)) AS 
max_page FROM abc
```

`SUBSTRING(column1, 4, length(column1)-3)` helps to get last 4 digits of `column1`. Then find `MAX()` from it.

Here `4` is the Starting index of required data ie, `XYZ1234` -> 1 is in 4th place. `3` is the number of characters that need to be removed (XYZ).

> SUBSTRING(string, start_pos, number_of_chars)

**string**  *(Required)*. The string to extract from

**start_pos**   *(Required)*. The position to start extraction from. The first position in string is 1

**number_of_chars**     *(Required)*. The number of characters to extract

> CAST(value AS type)

The `CAST()` function converts a value from one datatype to another datatype.

Comment: thanks for your support  i got the output as you mentioned ,will you please explain what is 4 and -3 in this case.